# When is the map $f$ diagonisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

We have the linear map $f:\mathbb{R}_2[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ with $$f(p(x))=10p(1)+5p(x)+3\lambda xp''(x)+4p'(x)$$ where $\mathbb{R}_2[x]=\{ax^2+bx+c:a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ with real coefficients.

How can we choose $\lambda$ so that $f$ is diagonisable?

If we write this in matrix form we have $$ f(p(x))=\begin{pmatrix}10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 3x\lambda & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p(1) \\ p(x) \\ p''(x) \\ p'(x)\end{pmatrix}$$ Is this the correct matrix form?

Now we have to check when the matrix is diagonisable, or not?

Comment: You should take a basis of $\mathbb R_2[x]$, for example $\{1, x, x^2\}$, and find the matrix of $f$ with respect to that basis. (It will be a $3\times 3$ matrix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard basis of $\mathbb R_2[x]$ is $\{1,x,x^2\}$ so that

$f(1)=15=15(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)$

$f(x)=14(1)+5(x)+0(x^2)$

$f(x^2)=10+(6\lambda+8) x+5x^2$

The matrix corresponding to $f$ is $T=\begin{pmatrix}15& 14& 10\\0& 5& 6\lambda+8\\ 0& 0& 5\end{pmatrix}$

For the repeated eigenvalue $t=5$, you need $AM=GM$ for which $Rank(T-5I)=1$ is required. This suggests $\lambda=-4/3$.

Comment: Ahh ok! I did a similar example and I got the matrix $$T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 4 & 12 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ how do we check in this case if it is diagonizable or not? The eigenvalues are $0$ (3 times) and $4$

Comment: It holds that for each eigenvalue the eigenspace has dimension equal to the multiplicity of the eingenvalue. Does this mean then that it is diagonalizable?

Comment: If algebraic multiplicity (AM) equals geometric multiplicity (GM) of each eigenvalue then matrix is diagonalizable. So, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)